# IF statement being ignored in C

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.141593
int main (void)
{
    float out, outrad, outarea, in, inrad, inarea, final;
    printf("Enter outer diameter: ");
    scanf("%f", &out);
    outrad = out/2;
    outarea = PI * (outrad * outrad);

    printf("Enter inner diameter: ");
    scanf("%f", &in);
    inrad = in/2;
    inarea = PI * (inrad * inrad);
    final = outarea - inarea;

    //if ( out < in)
    //{
    //    printf("Invald inputs: Inner diameter must be less than outer diameter\n");
    //}
    if ( out < 0 && in < 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid inputs: Both diameters must be positive.\n");
    }
    else if ( out < in )
    {
        printf("invalid inputs: Inner diameter must be less than outer diameter\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Surface area: %0.6f\n", final);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and works fine except it doesn't execute the first IF statement if I have inputs less than 0. It just continues to calculate the surface area regardless.  Am I missing some syntax?

```
Run 1
Enter outer diameter: 13.5
Enter inner diameter: 0
Surface area: 143.138824
Run2
Enter outer diameter: 5
Enter inner diameter: 4
Surface area: 7.068584
Run3
Enter outer diameter: 4
Enter inner diameter: 5
invalid inputs: Inner diameter must be less than outer diameter
Run4
Enter outer diameter: 4
Enter inner diameter: 0
Surface area: 12.566372
Run5
Enter outer diameter: 0
Enter inner diameter: 0
Surface area: 0.000000
```

Comment: Show a sample run with all inputs and outputs

Comment: Please format console text as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: I think you want to check 'out' or 'in' is below zero. use ||(or) operator instead of &&(and).

Comment: None of your tests are satisfying the first `if` condition. They must both be negative.

Comment: just realised.. sht. thanks

Comment: Been there done that.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Improve it, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Use `||` instead of `&&` in your condition.

In your sample input, you never even try to trigger this condition:

```
Run 1
Enter outer diameter: 13.5
Enter inner diameter: 0   // Is "in" less than zero?  NO! It is *exactly* zero
Surface area: 143.138824
```

If you want to test this:

```
Run 1
Enter outer diameter: 13.5
Enter inner diameter: -5   // Is "in" less than zero?  Yes!
Invalid inputs: Both diameters must be positive.
```

Comment: still ignores the first IF

Answer (score 1):

Replace `&&` with `||`.

Basically you want to run it if in OR out is less than zero.
It should run if both are less than zero though since in AND out are less than zero.

Comment: with || im literally getting the same result

Comment: Your example doesn't have any negative numbers as input. If you're expecting it to fail when they are equal to zero, you'll want to use less than or equal to zero instead of the strict inequality.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( out<0 &&  in < 0)
```

This is the error in your code. `&&` evaluates true only if both the conditions evaluate true. So even if one of your condition is true i.e. less than 0 and other is false i.e. greater than 0 the statement evaluates as false and the code is not executed. Therefore, you need an `||`evaluation so that even if only one of the conditions evaluate to true, your code is executed.

And I don't know if it is a typo or not but the code in current formatting should give compilation errors. But since it is compiling then you must have entered it incorrectly here. But anyways:

Lines 20 and 29

```
diameter\n");
```

are not commented and poorly formatted. So improve your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If

> Both diameters must be positive.

then

```
if( !(out > 0 && in > 0) )
{
    printf("Invalid inputs: Both diameters must be positive.\n");
}
```